# Socialite.js callback or loaded event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm implimenting [Socialite.js](https://github.com/dbushell/Socialite) for the first time. [It is a js plugin for loading social media plugins after page load, or whenever] It seems really great but I want to hide the loading plugins and display them after Socialite has done its magic. [opacity 0>1 with css transitions] The documentation says nothing about a callback and I can't find anything on google.

I would like to know:

- if Socialite has a callback?
- or if it gives a finished event I can listen for?
- or another way to detect if my social plugins [both fb and twitter] are loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not documented but can be found by reading source. Callback is called after each individual widget is loaded. If you are using jQuery you could use something like:

```
Socialite.load(null, null, null, function(target) {
    $(target).hide().fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Better way would be to hide widgets initially by css and call only:

```
Socialite.load(null, null, null, function(target) {
    $(target).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: Ah great. I've just tried this and this seems to fire at the same time as the plugins start to load, meaning not when they are totally ready. Any idea of a callback after all widgets are loaded? If not I can work with this.

Comment: I think the widget are loaded asynchronously. Callback fires when command to load widget was given. Maybe just add small delay before calling fadeIn()?

Comment: Yea I'm doing that sort of thing but obviously the delay can't exactly match the loading. But yes thanks for the answer I'll take it from here :}